# MMS to web application

Tags: mms, mms-gateway

I've scoured over the questions here, but cannot seem to find an answer, so I thought to ask.

I'm creating a web application that will take in pictures, using the EXIF information or other image meta data to automatically place it in a date specific location...which is fine and dandy when doing the normal upload via web.

However, I'm trying to figure out how users with feature phones (not smart phones like the iphone/android ones) can send MMS to be received by my web app.

I've checked with some companies, like openmarket.com, and it seems they have to broker this access with Tier 1 telecoms like ATT, Verizon, etc.....then they abstract and provide a gateway, I lease a shortcode and their gateway and use their api to post/get the MMS data.

I was wondering if there was a way around this?  this would help me out a great deal!

could i use email?
how does flickr.com acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your users to send MMS to an email address, and then parse the email.  There are libraries out there to do this; what language are you planning to use?